# How to mount a single directory on another directory in kernel module

Tags: linux, file, linux-kernel, filesystems, kernel-module

I want to mount a directory say dir1 over a mount point say /mnt/dir2.
How would i accomplish this using code in kernel module.

Note: I want to handle/create all inodes and dentries corresponding to newly created directory dir2.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried this far? Could you show us your previous attempts and the code involved? Why do you want to perform filesystem mounts from a kernel module? That is a thing more appropriate for user space, I think.

Comment: yes i am trying to make a filesystem for which i need to mount like this.

Comment: Show us some code, then. Explain why you don't use FUSE as well, that helps anyone trying to answer.

Comment: Why kernel code? You can simply do `mount --bind olddir newdir`